# Node async library binding of this

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, coffeescript

I am using the async library (https://github.com/caolan/async)
on node trying to execute multiple db queries async with mongoskin (https://github.com/guileen/node-mongoskin)

The problem is when using the map function like so

```
app.post '/events', (req, res) ->
  storage.events.getByUser req.session.authId, (events) ->
    async.map events, storage.codes.getCountByEvent, (err, results) ->
      res.send results
```

it is binding `@` to the global namespace on the `getCountByEvent` function, does anybody with experience with the async library able to give me guidance on the best way to fix this?

Here is the sample of the `storage.codes` implementation

```
class Codes
    constructor: (db) ->
        db.bind 'codes',
            getCountByEvent: (event, callback) ->
                @.find(event: event._id).toArray (err, res) ->
                    callback res.length

        return db.codes

exports.Codes = Codes
```

calling `getCountByEvent` outside of the `async.map` it will work fine

Thanks in advance

Comment: That actually doesn't work, I have tried it. getCountByEvent: (event, callback) =>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a version of `getCountByEvent` that's bound to the `storage.codes` object:

```
async.map events, storage.codes.getCountByEvent.bind(storage.codes), ...
```

Comment: Yes this will work, I was hopping for a way with async framework to bind the context correctly. I'll accept this answer if nobody has a different take on it. Thanks.

Comment: @BrianWigfield Well, this is the usual way to bind the iterator's context. Async uses Array::map behind the scenes; if you did the same directly, you'd have to bind the iterator the same way. Only alternative is do the same thing manually `bound -> (args...) storage.codes.getCountByEvent args...` - but why bother when you have `bind`?

Comment: This is definitely the easiest way. `Async` doesn't support passing in   a context argument. If this is on the client side, @Flambino's suggestion also works.